# How can i loop animate a set of images in animation node?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, 2d

I have a set of images to make a slideshow. I want to use animation node addon to animate the images.
All the images will have the same animation but will stay in front of the camera with different duration.
How can i do that?

The simple slideshow i have done so far as an example :
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, could you tell us more : How familiar are you with the add-on ? What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi, i have done very simple node trees, i am trying to increase my knowledge on the add on and do more complex technical node trees. This is what i have done for the slideshow, you can see on the original post i edited. I have been struggling to animate objects with the same animation looping but with different duration.